# JavaScript: Selenium clicks login button before I input password occasionally

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, promise

I want to log in twitter using selenium webdriver, this is my code:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
    forBrowser('chrome').
    build();

driver.get('https://twitter.com/login')
driver.findElement(By.className('js-username-field')).sendKeys('my email')
driver.findElement(By.className('js-password-field')).sendKeys('my pwd');
driver.findElement(By.css('button[type="submit"]')).click();
```

When I test my code, **occasionally** something wrong happened:

1. Selenium input email;
2. Selenium click log in button;

After my code run complete, the password field remains empty. This lead to login failure.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try once with keys up to login option.

```
driver.findElement(By.className('js-username-field')).sendKeys('my email',Keys.TAB,'my pwd',Keys.TAB,Keys.ENTER);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with adding a wait before the click method, as:

```
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css("button[type='submit']")));
```

This should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try code below and tell me if it works or not? If not, what do you see in console?

```
driver.get('https://twitter.com/login').then(function(){
    driver.findElement(By.className('js-username-field')).sendKeys('my email');
    driver.findElement(By.className('js-password-field')).sendKeys('my pwd');   

    driver.wait(function(){
        return driver.findElement(By.className('js-password-field')).getAttribute('value');
}, 10000).then(function(value){ console.log(value)});

    driver.findElement(By.css('button[type="submit"]')).click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of not giving wait time before and after the

driver.findElement(By.className('js-password-field')).sendKeys('my pwd');

Try giving the wait time.

public void myFunction() throws InterruptedException

```
{       
driver.get('https://twitter.com/login');  
driver.findElement(By.className('js-username-field')).sendKeys('my email');  
Thread.sleep(4000);   
driver.findElement(By.className('js-password-field')).sendKeys('my pwd');   
Thread.sleep(4000);  
driver.findElement(By.css('button[type="submit"]')).click();   
}
```

Also  you can try wait implicit or explicit way.

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.className('js-password-field'))));
        driver.findElement(By.className('js-password-field')).sendKeys('my pwd');
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

```
'var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
By = webdriver.By,
until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
forBrowser('chrome').
build();

driver.get('https://twitter.com/login')
driver.findElement(By.className('js-username-field')).sendKeys('my email')
driver.findElement(By.className('js-password-field')).sendKeys('my pwd');
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.css('button[type="submit"]')).click();'
```

Comment: Try using a simple implicit wait and see if this resolves the issue please.